# Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Chapter 9.2 tests failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm working through the latest version of Michael Hartl's tutorial, and I can't get a couple of tests from Chapter 9.2 to pass:

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec-authorization

I have verified my gem versions, restarted the Rails server, ran bundle update, and rebuilt the test database to no avail. I've recopied from the git repository, and gone over every line I thought was relevant. I haven't had any trouble up through chapter 9, but I'm trying to be thorough, especially with the web security parts like this one, because I want to make a new site using this model once I finish the the tutorial. Any help is deeply appreciated.

As a side note, the edit redirects appear to work fine, but the tests that use PUT are failing, even though they use the same redirect function in the controller, I don't understand why they would  behave differently. Again, thank you for any help.

John

Failure messages:

> 1) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Users controller submitting to the update action 
>       Failure/Error: specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
>         Expected response to be a redirect to >http://www.example.com/signin but was a redirect to >https://www.example.com/users/45
>       # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:60:in `block (6 levels) in top
>   (required)'
>
> 2) Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action 
>       Failure/Error: specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
>         Expected response to be a redirect to >http://www.example.com/ but was a redirect to >https://www.example.com/users/49
>       # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:77:in `block (5 levels) in 'top 
>   (required)'

Here is the authentication spec, where the 2 failing tests are coming from:
    require 'spec_helper'

```
describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do [...]

  describe "signin" do [...]

  describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      describe "in the Users controller" do

        describe "visiting the edit page" do
                          before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
              it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
        end

        describe "submitting to the update action" do
          before { put user_path(user) }
          specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) } #<---Failure 1
        end
      end
    end

    describe "as wrong user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
      before { sign_in user }

      describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
        before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
        it { should_not have_selector('title', text: full_title('Edit user')) }
      end

      describe "submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action" do
        before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) } #<--- Failure 2
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The sign_in function in utilities:

```
def sign_in(user)
  visit signin_path
  fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in"
  # Sign in when not using Capybara as well.
  cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

Here is the users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

   private

    def signed_in_user
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
        end
end
```

And my routes, just in case:

```
Railstut::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  match '/help',    to: "static_pages#help"
  match '/about',   to: "static_pages#about"
  match '/contact', to: "static_pages#contact"
end
```

Comment: which is the commit you are copying from? I have checked against [this](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/commit/9bbe3e844f5a5b366c46a80ec64ee0c214d7824d) but did not notice anything that is wrong with the files you have posted, so possibly the problem has to lie somewhere else

Comment: Yes, that is the version I am working with, 2nd edition:
https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. This was happening because I turned on SSL in the application controller. I added an environment test and everything passes now.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper

  if Rails.env.production? 
    force_ssl
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice work.  Please mark this question as solved so it doesn't come up in the unanswered questions list.